# Changing value of raster within set radius

Tags: raster, radius

I have a raster map of an aquifer. I want to alter it so that the water level changes around a point(an active pump). What i need is a way to select a radius on my raster and lower the Z value within that radius by a number thus creating a cone step by step.

Is there any simple way to do this?

I suspect that it’s possible with PyQGIS but i have only just started learning it.

Comment: Create the buffer as a vector polygon, rasterize the buffer with a fixed value, corresponding to the amount you want to subtract form the initial raster, then use raster calculator: initial raster - buffer-raster.